# Entity Framework - Convert an SQL query to Entity Framework Lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have this below query which I need to convert into a lambda expression:

```
select t.*
from (
   select DocId, max(Version) as maxversion
   from [DocumentVersion] group by DocId
) as x inner join [DocumentVersion] as t on f.DocId = x.docid and
       t.version = x.maxversion
where t.TestDocId =  12345
```

These are the column names =
Id,DocSecId,Version,    DocType,    DocId,  TestDocId,  AppId,  RppId,  Regions,    ExecutedDate    EffectiveDate,  Icheck, Vcheck, locked, Parentid,   childId,    LastCheckedId,  Modified,   Fresh

```
var dbData = db.DocumentVersion
    .Where(x => listofIds.Contains(x.DocTestId))
    .GroupBy(x => x.DocId).Select(
        g => new
        {
            DocId = g.Key,
            Version = g.Max(x => x.Version),
        })
    .ToList();
```

So far I have done the below query, but need to include all the columns in the output. In my case, I am getting two parameters as output - Count and Capacity:

Please help me with the code optimisation as well as the the output generation

Comment: EF deals with entities and LINQ isn't SQL. What does your query try to do? Retrieve the latest DocumentVersion for a specific document? Even in SQL there are easier ways to do this, eg `SELECT TOP 1 * From DocVersions where DocID=x ORDER BY Version desc`. Or do you want to do that for a list of documents?

Comment: I want to convert the above SQL into LINQ query. I have grouped it using DocId and Max(Version). The output of my LINQ query is Count and Capacity. I want to entire table columns in it like - DocSecId, DocType, DocId, AppId etc.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Try posting a sample set of data and your desired output. It sounds like you want to get document details for the latest version, but I don't know how/where "Count and Capacity" come from, or what other columns you expect and from where. When grouping data, the data output is either part of the grouping expression or aggregated (`Count`/`Max`/ etc) Adding columns to the grouping just makes the result more granular. (more specific groups)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you have two tables with one to many relationships `Document` and `DocumentVersion` and you want to retrieve the latest/max version for the `Documents` with a given specific list of `Ids`. If this is the case with EF Core 6 you can use the new `[MaxBy][1]` method and do something like

```
var documentVersions = db.DocumentVersion
   .Where(x => listofIds.Contains(x.DocTestId))
   .GroupBy(x => x.DocId)
   .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.Version))
   .ToList();
```

An implementation for EF Core 5 and the below version (including the original EF) prior to introducing the `MaxBy` operator will use the `Max` operator and will be something like

```
var documentVersions = db.DocumentVersion
   .Where(x => listofIds.Contains(x.DocTestId))
   .GroupBy(x => x.DocId)
   .Select(g => g.First(x => x.Version == g.Max(y =>  y.Version)))
   .ToList();
```